# Document command is not available whend using uidoc.copy

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I got an error 'Document command is not available' when the program hits the uidoc.Copy line. I have researched this error message. But all I get is only if it has anything to do with Edit Mode and I am not using that at all here.

```
    Sub Click(Source As Button)

' ===========================================================
' Get common username, mail server, and mailfile information 
  to be used on ComposeDocument method

    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim reg As New NotesRegistration
    Dim user As String

    reg.RegistrationServer = "Test"
    user = session.CommonUserName
    Call reg.GetUserInfo(user, _
    mailserver$, _
    mailfile$)
' ======================================================================    
    Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
    Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument
    Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument

    Call uidoc.GotoField("QSContactEMail")
    Call uidoc.SelectAll
    Call uidoc.Copy

    Set uidoc = workspace.ComposeDocument _
    (mailserver$, mailfile$, "Memo")
    Call uidoc.GotoField("Subject")
    Call uidoc.Paste
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use copy and paste to transfer values from one document to another. You can directly assign those values using document objects.

There are several methods to do this- here is one that is similar to yours. Replace everything below the second line with this:

```
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidoc As NotesUIDocument, newuidoc as NotesUIDocument

Set uidoc = workspace.CurrentDocument
Set newuidoc = workspace.ComposeDocument _
(mailserver$, mailfile$, "Memo")

Call newuidoc.FieldSetText("Subject", uidoc.FieldGetText("QSContactEMail"))

End Sub
```

Comment: Did this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if you have a field called $KeepPrivate set to "1". It will prevent copying.

The error can also happen if nothing is selected. Try STOP just before the line and make sure it is highlighted.

There are also other conditions listed here:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21094450

Comment: I do not see the $KeepPrivate field in the form. Also when I debug the code and stop before the copy, the field did not get hightlighted but the document looks like it got scrolled down. Does it matter that the field that I am trying to copy is a computed field?

Comment: It does matter that the field is computed. What happens is that the GotoField method does position the cursor, but since the cursor is not positioned in an editable field the SelectAll method works the way it does when the document is in read mode.  I.e., instead of selecting the field contents, it selects the entire document contents. The Copy method actually can work in that case (at least it does for me) but the Paste will probably fail unless you are pasting into a rich text field. So I'm not sure why Copy fails for you, but even if it did work it's probably not going to be what you want.